# How to moq setup IRepository<T>

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I am trying to setup like this:

```
[Test]
public void Observatoins_Were_Returned()
{
    using (var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose())
    {
        // Arrange
        mock.Mock<IRepository<WspObservation>>()
            .Setup(x => x.GetAll())
            .Returns(_observations);

        var sut = mock.Create<CommonServices>();                              
        WspResponse wspResponse;

        // Act
        var wspObservations = sut.GetAllObservations(out wspResponse);
        var expectedErrorCode = ResponseCodes.SUCCESS;

        // Assert
        // Assert.AreEqual(expectedErrorCode, wspResponse.ResponseCode);

    }
}
```

but when GetAllObservations() function is called it returns null in the actual code.

In the actual code IRepository is dependency injected which is working fine.

object that is being returned looks like this.

```
      var _observations = new List<WspObservation>();
        _observations.Add(new WspObservation() { DeviceName = "Devcie One", Steps = "3000"  });
        _observations.Add(new WspObservation() { DeviceName = "Devcie One", Steps = "2000" });
```

the actual function that is being tested looks like this

```
public List<WspObservation> GetAllObservations(out WspResponse getAllWspObservationsResponse)
    {
        List<WspObservation> allWspObservations = new List<WspObservation>();
        getAllWspObservationsResponse = new WspResponse();
        try
        {
            //some other Business Logic
            allWspObservations = _wspObsrep.GetAll().ToList();
            //some other Business Logic
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            getAllWspObservationsResponse.ResponseCode = ResponseCodes.DatabaseGetError;

        }
        return allWspObservations;
    }
```

dependency injection looks like this

```
    private IRepository<WspObservation> _wspObsrep;

    public CommonServices(IRepository<WspObservation> wspObsrep)
    {
        _wspObsrep = wspObsrep;
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so that your issue can be reproduced and a possible solution provided. Your current example does not provide enough details to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Looks like you create a mock of `IRepository<WspObservation>` and setup its `GetAll()` method to return `_observations`, but you don't keep a reference to the mock, which means there's no way you can get your mock of `CommonServices` to use it, which means that your setup is never called. Since you're working with loose mocks, the framework is creating its own `IRepository<WspObservation>` when it needs one, and all of its methods will return null. You need to devise a way to get your mock into `CommonServices`.

Comment: i have update the example

Answer (score 0):

What is the intention of

```
var sut = mock.Create<CommonServices>();
```

Isn't it better to Create the real SUT object and inject the IRepository mock?

I would do it this way:

```
var repoMock = mock.Mock<IRepository<WspObservation>>()
        .Setup(x => x.GetAll())
        .Returns(_observations);

var sut = new CommonServices(repoMock);
```